# impossible probabilistic inversion !!!

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to solve $r$ in terms of $L$ in which $L$ can be expressed in terms of $r$ as follows:
$$L = r^{\alpha}$$
where
$$ \alpha = \begin{cases}
\alpha_1,  &\text{with probability} \qquad e^{-\beta r} \\
\alpha_2,  &\text{with probability} \qquad 1-e^{-\beta r}
 \end{cases}$$
in other words $\alpha$ is a Bernoulli RV. But notice that probability of each outcome of $\alpha$ is a function of $r$.

How this can be done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is known in advance? What is observed?

Comment: nothing is observed. this is not an estimation problem guys. $L$ is modeled as above. in some integral i need to express $r$ in terms of $L$ instead. the problem is that the probability of $\alpha$ is a function of $r$ too. so i don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $\alpha$ is random doesn't change the fact that the relation $L=r^\alpha$ is valid all the time, so can be inverted deterministically. $r=L^{1/\alpha}$. Now if you want to estimate $r$ from an observed value of $L$ without knowledge of $\alpha$, that's another question, to which various stastistical theories can answer (maximum likelihood, bayesian stats...)

Comment: @JeanMarie of course, i edited, than you !

Comment: notice that $\alpha$ is a RV. then we expect that $r$ in terms of $L$ be a probabilistic, but how we can calculate the probabilities?
For example we must say something like this:
$$L = r^{1/\alpha_L} \qquad \text{with probability  } e^{f(L)}$$.